# When Formatting a float value then language change

Tags: java, string-formatting

I used java 12. when if i try to format float value like 2.006 to 2.01 then result language change. my code:

```
final DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
float twt = Float.parseFloat(decimalFormat.format(weight / 1000));

input : 2.026
output found: ২.০৩ (bangla language value)
```

please help me how can i solve this

Comment: Why are you formatting and parsing? `float twt = weight / 1000.0f;`

Comment: Did you read the `DecimalFormat` documentation, especially the part where it tells you not to call its constructor?

Comment: to format in 2 decimal places

Answer (score 0):

I think that snippet below going to help you.

```
float val = 2.025f;

System.out.println(val);    // 2.025
System.out.println(val / 1000); // 0.002025

System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%f\n", val); // 2.025000
System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%f\n", val / 1000);  // 0.002025

System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.2f\n", val);   // 2.03
System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.2f\n", val / 1000);    // 0.00
```